# What is the maximum number of ssh connections we can do and how can i check in linux

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, openssh

I am trying to figure out how many max number of ssh connections we can do to a machine.

where we need to change this value if i want more or reduce the connections. i mean the path of the file.

Comment: It really depends on *what* you want limit. Per user logins can be limited in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Also the daemon is limited to maximum number of processes that can create and number of open files (every connection opens a file).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is in the `man sshd_config`, the **MaxSessions** and **MaxStartups** fields

http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config&sec=5

File and path:

```
 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: This is actually not true. `MaxSessions` is related to sessions in one TCP connection and `MaxStartups` apply only for number of simultanous *unauthenticated* connections.